# Filtering table with Spark SQL to rows with minimum value of column

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I apologize in advance for what has got to be a very simple question.  But I'm trying to filter a table down to only the rows that contain the minimum distance, where distance itself is calculated from another table.

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
    shape_id, 
    ST_Distance(ST_Point(-87.65751647949219, 41.89625930786133), geom) AS distance
FROM routes) a
WHERE distance = (SELECT MIN(distance) FROM a)
LIMIT 50
```

I've also tried:

```
"""SELECT shape_id, ST_Distance(ST_Point(-87.65751647949219, 41.89625930786133), geom) AS distance
FROM routes a
WHERE distance = (select MIN(distance) from a)
LIMIT 50
"""
```

But I always get:
`Table or view not found: a`

Can someone please help me with the syntax here?

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using? The subqueries were not supported for Spark version <= 2.0

Comment: I'm using 2.3.2